# How to create NSURLRequest with HTTPHeaderField

Tags: iphone

I have curl request as follow

curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",oauth_consumer_key="de4422f-f3ff-4929-bb65-eadc6f5218e2",oauth_token="85ab49a-9081-4641-812c-09d3130e3a8",oauth_signature="0723ba36-8d19-4fab-9337-7e81004655c%26e385879b-0b57-481b-a8fc-8eb1426fc72"' 'https://external.ningapis.com/xn/rest/ippinn/1.0/User/?author=0n1s8aln92xhx&fields=iconUrl,email,url,fullName,birthdate,gender'

I want to create same request using NSURLRequest 
I tried it and search on forum get lots of solution but it do not get success

I did following code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://external.ningapis.com/xn/rest/ippinn/1.0/User/?author=0n1s8aln92xhr&fields=iconUrl,email,url,fullName,birthdate,gender"];  
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString  *authorization = @"OAuth ";
authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"oauth_signature_method=%@",@"PLAINTEXT"];
authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_consumer_key=%@",@"de4422f-f3ff-4929-bb65-eadc6f5218e2"];
authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_token=%@",@"85ab49a-9081-4641-812c-09d3130e3a8"];
authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_signature=%@",@"0723ba36-8d19-4fab-9337-7e81004655c%26e385879b-0b57-481b-a8fc-8eb1426fc72"];

NSLog(@"authorization =>%@",authorization);
[request setValue: authorization forHTTPHeaderField: @"Authorization"];

 self.connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (_connection) {
    self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
```

Please suggest me where i m going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://external.ningapis.com/xn/rest/ippinn/1.0/User/?author=0n1s8aln92xhr&fields=iconUrl,email,url,fullName,birthdate,gender"];  
    NSString  *authorization = @"OAuth ";
    authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"oauth_signature_method=%@",@"PLAINTEXT"];
    authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_consumer_key=%@",@"de4422f-f3ff-4929-bb65-eadc6f5218e2"];
    authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_token=%@",@"85ab49a-9081-4641-812c-09d3130e3a8"];
    authorization  = [authorization stringByAppendingFormat:@"&oauth_signature=%@",@"0723ba36-8d19-4fab-9337-7e81004655c%26e385879b-0b57-481b-a8fc-8eb1426fc72"];
    NSData *postData = [authorization dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [urlRequest setURL:url];
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"charset"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *tmpConn = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self] autorelease];
    self.connection = tmpConn;//I suppose "connection" is a retained property 
    if (_connection) {
        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Teodor thanks for answer. I tried it but still i get response from server is "    code = 1;
    reason = "A required parameter wasn't received. These parameters must be present. oauth_signature_method";
    status = 400;
    subcode = 9;
    success = 0;
    trace = "8a5d4a32-256c-4c0b-9e0d-54e9a05cebc7";
}
" what would be possible reason.

Comment: take e look to the server side, see the list of parameters that the service needs to get from your request. there must be mandatory parameters as well as optional ones (depending on how they are set). make sure you are sending all mandatory parameters in your request.

Comment: i come across observation. If i send with "GET" http method we get data. Thanks for answer.